# Delete row form Primefaces LazyDataModel

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a table with a date column that always null. The data is a LazyDataModel child. Also i have row editing.

```
 <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="Var" value="#{tableBean.model}" 
lazy="true"...........


        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{tableBean.onRowEdit}"
                update=":dataTableForm:messages"/>


        <p:column sortBy="VarName">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{msg['Var.table.header.assignee']}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{Var.Name}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <h:inputText id="assigneeNameInput" styleClass="row-input" value="#{Var.Name}"/>
                    <p:message for="assigneeNameInput"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{msg['var.table.header.action']}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <p:rowEditor/>
        </p:column>
```

I need to delete edited row if date column was filled.

I try this

```
public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
        Var updatedVar = (Var) event.getObject();
    if (updatedVar.getReturnDate() != null) {
        updatedVar = null;
    } 
}
```

And this

```
public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
        Var updatedVar = (Var) event.getObject();
    if (updatedVar.getReturnDate() != null) {
         ((List<T>) getWrappedData()).remove(oldEntry);
    } 
}
```

Both attempts did not work, only if update table twice via `remoteCommand` . Suggest the decision. Thanks!

Edit: Data removed from lazydatamodel, but on page i still had updated row.

Edit : JSF application lifecycle consist of six phases.

**Phase 4:Update model values** :
After the JSF checks that the data is valid, it walks over the component tree and set the corresponding server-side object properties to the components' local values. The JSF will update the bean properties corresponding to input component's value attribute.

**Phase 5: Invoke application** :
During this phase, the JSF handles any application-level events, such as submitting a form / linking to another page.

So, invocation onRowEdit() method occur after dataTable's update.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Is the data not removed from the backing model? Is the table not reflecting the change? are your methods not being executed?

Comment: @BalusC As i understand, p:ajax automatically update form within which it is located, cuz dataTable after accepting row contains updated row. Correct me please, if i miss something.